# Un-Noticed Vulnerability, I need to know if i should do anything

Tags: security, cloudflare

## Possible Web-Site Vulnerability.

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, *but* I am running my own website, that is still currently being developed, but since it is 'Open as Beta' it is accessible on the web. 
I was checking my CloudFlare Web-Site analytics and saw some rather disturbing information:

---

http://gyazo.com/faac084b96d2812ab1e21e102818f718

> In case the image doen't work:
>
> > - For China, it says: 7 known threats,
> > - For USA, it says:   4 known threats,
> > - For Korea it says: 1 known threat.

---

**Should i be concerned about this and what should i do, if anything, about it?**
**Note**: Those stats are for the past 30 days only, since over the entirety of the time the site has been running, there has been near enough the same stats.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about that as much as you are. The threat could be a spammer or something, so it isn't indicating the severity of the threat. That's also a pretty low number of threats overall...